# "Unknown error, the response body from fetch is: undefined" at Auth.confirmSignIn

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

I am trying to send the verification code received by the user to confirm the signIn, I have the SMS_MFA enabled. However, I keep getting this error `Unknown error, the response body from fetch is: undefined` and thats all I get, there is nothing else to help me understand what the error is about. And everything else is working fine, I call signIn, signUp, confirmSignUp and resendSignUp, they all work fine. The problem is only with confirmSignIn and I have no idea what it could be, I already researched online, but had no success. Another strange thing that happens, when I enter the wrong code, it shows me the 'CodeMismatchException', but it fails with 'Unknown error' when code is the right one. PS: I already have cognito configured to work with SMS MFA

I'am having this problem in android and iOS. React native version 0.55.4 and aws-amplify version ^1.0.11

I have a file where a call all the Auth functions and export them

```
export const confirmSignIn = (cognitoUser, code) => Auth.confirmSignIn(cognitoUser, code, 'SMS_MFA');
```

Then I call that confirmSignIn function from a different file

```
confirmSignIn(cognitoUser, code).then((userSession) => {
     console.log(userSession);
  }).catch((error) => {
     switch (error.name) {
       case 'CodeMismatchException':
        this.codeInput.clear();
        break;
       default:
        console.log(error);
        break;
    }
  });
```

I already tried upgrading aws-amplify version, but it didn't work, tried to do it with `cognitoUser.sendMFACode()` but didn't work either. I just keep getting `Unknown error, the response body from fetch is: undefined`

I also opened an [issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1672) in the aws-amplify repo.